# DataGrid in User Control throws exception Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject'

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a project containing a DataGrid which I've implemented a handy sorting and filtering UI for. It's so handy in fact that I've extracted the relevant code into a UserControl which I've embedded in a test project. I've added DependencyProperties for the DataGrid controls which I want available to the consumer of the UserControl.  So far so good.

The problem began when I set the DataGrid property IsReadOnly="False". At that point any operation on its ItemsSource throws an exception.

The DataGrid in the original project is perfectly happy with IsReadOnly="False" and the UserControl works OK with IsReadOnly="True". In the debugger (VS 2017) everything is correctly typed and all the data is as expected.

One failure occurs at the code below

```
this.Xrefs.Cast<ProductXref>().ToList()
```

where

```
public ICollectionView Xrefs { get; set; }
```

is set from my ItemsSource DependencyProperty.

In other locations I get an `Object does not match target type` exception.
Is VS wrapping the ItemsSource collection in another object but only when the DataGrid is in a UserControl and is set to not readonly?

I appreciate that I can leave the DataGrid readonly and use a child form for editing a row, but I prefer editing in place if possible.

Comment: So you are trying to cast Xrefs to type ProductXref? or to a collection of type ProductXref?

Comment: ICollectionView doesn't have a ToList() method so you have to Cast it to get the List. This statement produces a List of type ProductXref and these are a filtered subset of the ICollectionView.SourceCollection.

Comment: You shouldn't really access your items via the `ICollectionView` interface. Instead, access your items via the original items collection you used to create your `ICollectionView Xrefs`.

Comment: @dymanoid the original collection isn't filtered is it? I thought the whole purpose of ICollectionView is the filtering/sorting. Also, the code works fine when I have the DataGrid in a Window, the problem occurs when the DataGrid is in a UserControl.

Comment: This isn't exactly a solution, but I had a similar problem yesterday when my DataGrid was wrapped in another element. I had it sorted into collapsible groups, and that grouping was the `NamedObject` that was causing the issue. If you have anything like that, try examining it closely, you *might* find your error there.

Comment: @Cubemaster thanks for the suggestion, happily the problem is solved, the blank row at the end of the DataGrid. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of casting all items in the collection view, you could use the `OfType<T>` method to only get the `ProductXref` objects:

```
this.Xrefs.OfType<ProductXref>().ToList();
```

There may be other type of objects in the collection view, like for example a placeholder for the last "empty" row that you will typically see in a `DataGrid`.

Comment: Got it in one! I also had CanUserAddRows="True" so there is indeed a placeholder object. Big thank you.

Comment: Finally after wasting a lot of time... Thank you! For me the DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" is the solution.